# Does using the third conditional make this argument circular?

Tags: conditional-constructions, past-vs-past-perfect, irrealis-mood

I was wondering which conditional would be appropriate in the following argument.

> There's no evidence to support the opposition's claim that a black hole resulted from the supernova.  Furthermore, **if a black hole (had) resulted from the supernova**, then our instruments would have detected it.  Thus, the opposition is wrong.

I was thinking of using the third conditional to express confidence that the black hole did not result, but then I realized that suggesting the impossibility of the black hole resulting from the supernova in a premise might be circular.

So, my question is should I keep the third conditional

> If a black hole had resulted from the supernova...

or change the "if" clause to simple past

> If a black hole resulted from the supernova...

?

Comment: The ***grammatical*** question is whether you want the if clause to be saying that the black hole is counterfactual (use past perfect) or simply to not commit yourself one way or the other as to whether a black hole resulted or not (use simple past). They both work here, and the question is which is more appropriate to use in a debate.

Comment: I've [moved the discussion about conditionals to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62328/discussion-on-question-by-chongdogmillionaire-does-using-the-third-conditional-m). Please feel free to continue it there - I think it's a valuable discussion, but it's detracting somewhat from the question.